# Could not load file

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yl38.png)I am executing the application the error occurred although the reference is already there,what could be the solution?

> 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'NationalInstruments.UI.WindowsForms, Version=13.0.40.242,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dc6ad606294fc298' or one of its
>   dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131515)'

Version Information:
Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yl38.png)

Comment: There can be a million solutions to your problem, but we need to see your code in order to help you further. You might want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a good understanding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Then it may be as the message says one of its dependencies is not found, check if you can find the needed dependency from the exception info.

Answer (score 1):

there could be many reasons. Try following:

- are you using correct version (ie, in your web.config version 13.x is defined, file is version 12.x)
- is this assembly appropriate for your .net version (maybe assembly is for .NET 3.5 and you're trying to use it with 4.0)
- are you using winforms version instead of asp.net version
- is your assembly on correct location...
- is your assembly correctly installed in GAC?

Comment: Neither its a version issue nor the location is incorrect, still the error is there

Comment: but, are you sure you're using correct version. Assembly name is `NationalInstruments.UI.**WindowsForms**` and you're using it in asp.net project... (according to question tag). Also, try deleting temporary internet files (`%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`) and rebuilding solution